MySQL query with pagination gets slower with every next page
I doing export so execute a lot of queries and in every call PDOStatement->execute is slower. This is same sql, only diff is offset. If that matter this is query:
SELECT `main_table`.*,
       `p`.`method`      AS `payment_method`,
       `ba`.`country_id` AS `billing_country`,
       `ba`.`region`     AS `billing_region`,
       `ba`.`city`       AS `billing_city`,
       `ba`.`postcode`   AS `billing_postcode`,
       `ba`.`vat_id`     AS `billing_vat_id`,
       `sa`.`country_id` AS `shipping_country`,
       `sa`.`region`     AS `shipping_region`,
       `sa`.`city`       AS `shipping_city`,
       `sa`.`postcode`   AS `shipping_postcode`,
       `sa`.`vat_id`     AS `shipping_vat_id`
FROM `sales_order` AS `main_table`
         INNER JOIN `sales_order_payment` AS `p` ON main_table.entity_id = p.parent_id
         INNER JOIN `sales_order_address` AS `ba` ON main_table.entity_id = ba.parent_id AND ba.address_type = "billing"
         INNER JOIN `sales_order_address` AS `sa`
                    ON main_table.entity_id = sa.parent_id AND sa.address_type = "shipping"
WHERE (`updated_at` <= '2024-09-03 07:59:33')
  AND (`status` IN ('complete', 'sent', 'closed'))
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 1500

There i debug: vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php::_execute
        if ($specialExecute) {
            return $this->_executeWithBinding($params);
        } else {
            return $this->tryExecute(function () use ($params) {
                $startTimex = microtime(true);

                if (!empty($params)) {
                    $res = $this->_stmt->execute($params);
                } else {
                    $res = $this->_stmt->execute();
                }

                echo 'Time X: ' . (int)((microtime(true) - $startTimex) * 1000000) . PHP_EOL;

                return $res;
                //return !empty($params) ? $this->_stmt->execute($params) : $this->_stmt->execute();
            });
        }
    }

This is printed times:

As you see time is increasing and this is significant after more than 200 page.
Anyone has encountered this problem and knows what to do about it?
Edit: Same problem with simple query without joins and when i use mysqli.

It suggests that there is an issue with how your tables are indexed.

@droopsnoot Same problem with simple query without joins, can you clarify?

The reason is obvious, and explained in the linked question. How to fix is not that simple. First of all i would drop the useless updated_at condition. OR, limit it from the bottom. Then create index on status. In case we keep the updated_at condition, the index should be on (updated_at, status).

@YourCommonSense Ok, so i tested this sql: SELECT main_table.* FROM sales_orderASmain_table LIMIT 100 OFFSET %s limit and offet is need, i test pagination. Results: first time: 1794, last time: 24205. Query is faster but still time is increasing. It is because of LIMIT?

Yes, it is because of limit

https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page, i.e. OFFSET is the problem.

Thank you, i learn something new today XD
After i changed for order by entity_id asc and where entity_id > last_entity_id there is no problem with increase time.
